# Creating a list of bound components

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm trying to make an app that shows a hand of cards, and the cards are changeable on click.

I have a hand component, and a card component.

hand.html:

```
<div class="col-lg-1" *ngFor="let card of cards">
        <app-card [card]="card"></app-card>
</div>
```

and app-card has it's own template that shows the number and suit of the card.

hand.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CardComponent } from '../card/card.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hand',
  templateUrl: './hand.component.html'
})
export class HandComponent implements OnInit {
cards:CardComponent[] = [];

  constructor() {
    //Fill hand with 12 cards
    Array.from(Array(12)).forEach((x, i) => {
     this.cards.push( new CardComponent() );
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and then the card.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-card',
  templateUrl: './card.component.html'
})
export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {

  }

  @Input()
  card: Card;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.card.number = 2;
    this.card.suit = 'diamonds';
  }

  changeNumber( num ){
    this.card.number = num;
  }


}

interface Card{
    suit:string;
    number:number;
}
```

As it stands now, I get my list of cards, all with the initialized 2 of diamonds value. When I try to trigger the changeNumber function, say from an onclick event on the card element, I get an error that says "cannot set property 'number' of undefined.

So I'm real confused, why can I set the initial value in the ngOnInit, but trying the set the value again, after initialization, the card property suddenly doesn't exist (even though the values of card are being displayed on the page).

I'm still trying to figured out @Input, and might be misusing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cards should not be an array of card components, but rather an array of cards.

So instead of this:

```
cards:CardComponent[] = [];
```

It should be this:

```
cards: Card[] = [];
```

This code:

```
<div class="col-lg-1" *ngFor="let card of cards">
        <app-card [card]="card"></app-card>
</div>
```

Will then create the appropriate number of CardComponent instances for you.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're getting at. Creating card interfaces makes more sense than creating components. But now how do I access the components that were created from the interface data? 

Before I was doing this:
 `(click)="card.changeNumber(4)"`

But now card isn't a component. also, even if I could access it, would the changes made to the Card component be bound the the values of the interface objects stored in the hand? Now my hand wouldn't know when the individual card values change.

Comment: It would just become this: `(click)="card.number=4"`

Comment: If you'd like to build a plunker outlining any remaining issues we could take a look.

Comment: Yeah, that would help a lot, but I just _don't_ get how to build out anything more than a single page app in plunkr.

The alteration you gave in your last comment works fine. But I'm going to need to access the component at _some_ point. Like when I want to change the suit of the card, I'm going to need real functionality. I guess I could put it in the hand component, but that just feels like work around.

Comment: It is not "normal" in Angular to get instances of components and use them as you are. It is much more "normal" to access component properties. And regarding your plunker question, use the New button drop down and select Angular. Then use the New file link in the file area on the left to create a new file. add the path in the new file name, such as "src/card.ts". Hope this helps.

Comment: So just as a best practice question, do you think the functions for checking and altering card data should be in the hand component, or would you create some abstraction layer?

Comment: Normally, the component's template accesses the properties of the component directly by way of data binding.